# Microsoft pubCenter applicationId vs Identity in appmanifest.xml

Tags: windows-8.1

I am developing an app for windows 8. Visual studio generated an application id for me. It looks like:

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest">
  <Identity Name="XXX" Version="1.0.0.0" />
```

in the manifest file (actual id is replaced with XXX in above). I also created a pubCenter account and it generated an application id that is supposed to be used like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-walkthroughs-html5(v=msads.10).aspx)

```
<div id="myAd" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0px; width: 250px; height: 250px; z-index: 1" 
      data-win-control="MicrosoftNSJS.Advertising.AdControl" 
      data-win-options="{applicationId: 'd25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab', adUnitId: '10043107'}">
    </div>
```

**Question: Is it okay for the app id in manifest to differ from pubcenter app id?** I am guessing answer is yes since the first one is id of app in the store and the second id is used to identify the app for pubcenter advertising, but I want to be sure.

Also follow up question is that there is also an App name in pubcenter and an app name in manifest.xml. **Can they be different as well?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the app ID in manifest will actually always be different than the pubcenter appId. the two IDs identify the app in two different systems just like one has a student id and another id for the health club / library.